# ¿Como rellenar un archivo de excel a traves de una plantilla ya creada?

Tags: c#, asp.net, epplus

Hola amigos espero me puedan ayudar con la solución a mi pregunta.

Tengo un método que me crea un excel desde cero a partir de un dataTable con epplus, pero mi problema es que ya tengo una plantilla con los encabezados de mi tabla y lo que quiero es rellenar esa plantilla de excel con los datos, ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? de antemano gracias.

Este es mi código para crear el excel sin rellenar la plantilla.

```
public void ExporttoExcel(DataTable table, string filename)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Resultados_Finales.xlsx");

        using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(filename);
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);
            ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();                
            ws.Column(74).Style.Locked = false;
            ws.Column(75).Style.Locked = false;
            ws.Column(88).Style.Locked = false;
            ws.Column(89).Style.Locked = false;
            ws.Column(90).Style.Locked = false;
            ws.Column(91).Style.Locked = false;
            ws.Column(92).Style.Locked = false;
            ws.Column(93).Style.Locked = false;
            ws.Column(94).Style.Locked = false;
            ws.Cells["BV1:BW1"].Style.Locked = true;
            ws.Cells["CJ1:CP1"].Style.Locked = true;
            ws.Protection.IsProtected = true;
            var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            pack.SaveAs(ms);
            ms.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer una modificación a un archivo existente de `Excel` con `EPPlus`, puedes hacer lo siguiente. Tengo un archivo en la siguiente ruta:

> C:\COMPARTIDO_SERVIDOR\Report_22042019_211801.xlsx

Para modificarlo, puedo hacer lo siguiente:

```
var file = new FileInfo(@"C:\COMPARTIDO_SERVIDOR\Report_22042019_211801.xlsx");
using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(file))
{ /*Obtiene el libro donde quiero meter el nuevo dato*/
    var sheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    /*Selecciono el rango de celdas a modificar, los combino y meto el texto centrado*/
    var cell = sheet.Cells["B6:F6"];
    cell.Merge = true;
    cell.Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
    cell.Value = "Nueva Linea Centrada";
   /*Guardo el cambio*/
    excel.Save();
}
```

En ese ejemplo, solo agregué en la fila 6 de la columna B a la F un texto "Nueva Linea Centrada". Puedes aplicarlo con los datos que deseas agregar dinámicamente.

Comment: Hola @Gabriel Aragon y si mi archivo de excel lo  tengo en una carpeta y necesito descargarlo tendria que cambiar mi código para descargarlo.

Comment: Hola @SHINOBI, me gustaría saber a qué te refieres con "descargarlo", es decir, necesitas copiar tu archivo plantilla a otro directorio sin afectar tu plantilla?, en el mismo código que te compartí puedes sustituir la linea `excel.Save();` por lo siguiente: `using (Stream writer = new FileStream(
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Nuevo archivo.xlsx"),
FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{ excel.SaveAs(writer); }` puedes sustituir el nombre de archivo y su ubicación para crear tu copia donde necesites.

Comment: Hola @Gabriel Aragon exactamente solo que yo tengo mi aplicación web en asp.net c# por lo que en mi capa de presentación esta así
Reportes -- Carpeta
  Plantilla_Excel.xlsx --Archivo dentro de carpeta
Por lo que quiero pasar esa ruta de ese archivo para rellenarlo con datos de mi DataTable y descargarlo.

Comment: @SHINOBI hice un pequeño proyecto test y calé metiendo un archivo **Excel** en la carpeta **App_Data** del proyecto; para acceder a la ruta de este archivo (y abrirlo con un `Process`) lo hice con esta función: `var pathExcel = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Plantilla.xlsx");` que prácticamente te trae un archivo en cualquier ubicación interna de tu programa. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola @Gabriel Aragon gracias por tu ayuda he modificado mi código y ya se descarga mi archivo con la plantilla que utilizo. Gracias.