# Abrir y llenar una plantilla Excel con C#

Tags: c#

Necesito abrir una plantilla de excel ya hecha, en la columna A2 y A3 debe insertarse un "ID Cliente" que lo tengo en un textbox, necesito abrir la plantilla llamada "envio_COD.xls" desde C# e insertarle los datos en A2 y A3, agradecería de su ayuda.

Comment: esta pregunta ya fue resuelta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/256538/como-rellenar-un-archivo-de-excel-a-traves-de-una-plantilla-ya-creada).

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: [La solución la enconré aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/256538/como-rellenar-un-archivo-de-excel-a-traves-de-una-plantilla-ya-creada)
Ya estaba cerrada en otra parte de StackOverflow